# jQuery slide animation on existing divs after prependTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this semi-slider-style UI where new terms are added in from the left: http://jsfiddle.net/v4v5cvkz/.  I'm using the jQuery prependTo function to do this.  My issue is that I want the terms that are already displayed to perform an animated slide to the right when a new term gets added, rather than suddenly "appear" in the correct position.  I did try adding a "displayed" class to terms that had successfully shown up, and tried adding a slide-to-right animation after that, but that didn't quite achieve the effect I was going for (the "displayed" objects were moved much further to the right than I expected).

Here is the problematic code (you'll probably want to view the fiddle to see it in context though):

```
function addToStream(term, delay) {
    setTimeout(function(){        
        $("<div />")
        .addClass("stream_term")
        .html(term)
        .css({
            opacity: 0
        })
        .prependTo("#stream_terms")
        .animate({opacity:1}, 
                 {  duration: 1000,
                    complete: function() {
                        $(this).addClass("displayed");
                    }
                });
    }, delay);
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.  Thank-you!

*Note: I have access to jQuery UI in my code, though it isn't linked in the fiddle.  Also, if anyone knows of a plugin that can do this sort of thing better than I can, please let me know.  The closest one I was able to find was [Fraction Slider](http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/), but I didn't find it obvious how to create a similar UI with it (it might also be overkill for my purposes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
function addToStream(term, delay) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var newDiv = $("<div />");

        newDiv.addClass("stream_term")
        .html(term)
        .css({
            opacity: 0,
            display: 'none'
        }).prependTo("#stream_terms");

        var width = newDiv.width();
        var height = newDiv.height();

        newDiv.css({
            width: 0,
            height: height,
            display: 'inline-block'
        })
        .animate({
            width: width,
            margin: '0 10px',
            padding: '5px 10px'
        }, 1000)
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function(){
            $(this).addClass("displayed");
        });
    }, delay);
}
```

It also needs the following CSS changes:

```
.stream_term {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/StathisG/hqg29p6r/1/

Comment: Yup, that would do it - thanks so much!  I did notice that the animation is a little bit choppy though, but it probably can't be helped.

Comment: @Brutalisk Animating the margin and padding values should remove this issue. I updated my answer and demo.

Comment: Perfect!  Works like a charm!